# Is a straight and a flush a straight flush?

Tags: texas-hold-em, flush

e.g. having the cards on table 5♡6♡7♡J♡A♠

- Player 1 has 8♡4♡
- Player 2 has 8♣9♡

Player 1 obviously has the straight flush 4-8 ♡ and is much higher than Player 2 who has a flush of hearts and a higher straight - does he still lose? Does P2 currently have a straight flush?

'Have been playing with my brother, I'm interested if I won.

Off-topic: People with more than 150 reputation: Please add the keyword 'straight'

Comment: Poker hands have exactly FIVE CARDS, no more, no fewer. Your best 5-card hand is the flush, and you only get to play one hand--your best five cards.

Comment: @anatoly TL:DR, P2 does not have a straight flush

Comment: @sakon Thank your for the response! Indeed, a straight flush is only a straight that is also a flush, and not the existence of a flush and a straight! Thank you all for the response! I only recently figured out that all hands have maximal five cards, so a "Three pair" also doesn't exist..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're playing Texas Hold'em. Player 1 wins the game. A straight in combination with a flush with different cards is the best hand a flush. The hand only looks at the first 5 best cards or best combination with maximal 5 cards. The rest of the cards don't count.

In your situation is this:

- Player 1: 4♥5♥6♥7♥8♥ → 8 high straight flush
- Player 2: 5♥6♥7♡9♥J♥ → jack high flush *(also when player 2 could make a 9 high straight, a jack high flush is the best hand)*